# check if the word in the set equals word in outside file

Tags: java, file, io, set, cpu-word

I have a set of words and an outside file.
I want to check if a word in the set is already present in the outside file. If the word is already in the file, then do nothing, if the word is not in the outside file already, then add it to the outside file.
This is the code I have written:

```
public static void toFile(Set<String> vocab, String filename)
    {   
        try 
        {
            for(String vocabWord : vocab)
            {
                File file = new File(filename);   
                Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file);      
                
                while(sc2.hasNextLine()) 
                {
                    String docWord = sc2.nextLine();
                    if (!(vocabWord.equals(docWord))) 
                    {
                        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
                        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(myWriter);
        
                        printWriter.println(vocabWord);
                        printWriter.close();
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                } 
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am using three different text documents to test it, have the line "test file one", "test file two", and "test file three".
The output I was expecting was: "test file three" (it is connected with a stop list which one and two are part of, and has been working)
However, when I run it, either with only one of the files or all three consecutively, the file always comes out empty.
I tried changing up things in the method, but nothing has worked, I either get an infinite loop or nothing in the outside file.
I am not sure what I am missing... I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and  added some comments for explanation. I have tested on local machine and it works

```
 public static void toFile(Set<String> vocab, String filename) {
    try {
        for(String vocabWord : vocab) {
            //task for each String in our Set
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file);

            boolean exists = false;//lets say it doesn't exist
            while(sc2.hasNextLine()) {
                //task for each line in the text
                //search the whole file first for the word 
                String docWord = sc2.nextLine();
                if (docWord.equals(vocabWord)){
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (!exists) {
                //add the vocabWord only if it doesnt exists
                FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(myWriter);

                printWriter.println(vocabWord);
                printWriter.close();
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To append the missing vocabulary in order of vocab, you can reduce the file operations
as such:

```
public static void toFile(Set<String> vocab, String filename) {
    try {
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        Path path = Paths.get(filename);
        Set<String> existing = Files.lines(path, charset)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        if (!existing.isEmpty()) {
            try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset,
                     StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                 PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
                vocab.stream()
                        .filter(word -> !existing.contains(word))
                        .forEach(word -> printWriter.println(word));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```